# Change boxplot background fill to white

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a boxplot using the following code -

```
ggplot(xray50g, aes(fill = SupplyingSite, x = factor(SupplyingSite, level = level_order), y = 
DefScore)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  # REDUCE X AXIS TEXT SIZE
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
  # USE ENVSTATS PACKAGE TO INCLUDE SAMPLE SIZE
  stat_n_text(size = 3) +
  # INCLUDE CALCULATED MEAN VALUES
  stat_summary(fun = mean, colour = "orange", geom = "point", size = 2,show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_text(data = means, vjust = -1.5, hjust = -0.18, size = 3, aes(label = round(DefScore, 2), 
                                                                y = DefScore + 0.08)) +
  # ADD HORIZONTAL LINE AT BASE MEAN
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(xray50g$DefScore), linetype = 2) +
  # ADD GLOBAL ANNOVA P-VALUE
  stat_compare_means(method = "anova", label.y = 26, size = 4) +
  # PAIRWISE COMPARISON AGAINST ALL
  stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "t.test", ref.group = ".all.",
                 label.y = 24, size = 4) +
  # USE ANNOTATE FUNCTION TO ADD MEAN PREVALENCE VALUE
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 8.5, y = 3.4, label = overallmean2, color = "red", size = 3)
```

The plot looks like this with a grey background -
[image]

What I would like is for the plot to have a white background like this example -

[image]

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html for example `theme_minimal()` or `theme_classic()`

Comment: Thank you, theme_classic() was exactly what I was looking for!